# What is the oldest state/nation that has abolished the death penalty?

Tags: law, death-penalty

In 1846 the state of Michigan became the first state in the United States to abolish the use of the death penalty, which still stands today.

Is there any country (or state/province/etc.) elsewhere that has had the death penalty abolished for longer **and** still has it abolished?

Comment: Note that even though the Catholic Church is well-known for being against the Death Penalty, [Vatican City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_Vatican_City) only abolished it in 1969.

Comment: @T.E.D. A side note: Catholic Church as a whole is not against the death penalty. In [the Catechism 2267](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7Z.HTM) the DP is still allowed. Only the people of the Church can be against (like popes, bishops etc.).

Comment: People accused of (some types of) crimes in Michigan are still at risk of the federal death penalty of the United States, so I would say Venezuela "wins" (if Olivier's answer is correct), even if abolition took place at a later point in time.

Comment: @ZeekLTK Are you somehow unsatisfied with the current answer to your question? If so, it could be nice to explain why. If you are satisfied, it is also nice to accept the answer: the SE websites work much better in this way.

Comment: I can't find source, but I'm pretty sure the Netherlands abolished it earliest, in Europe at least.

Comment: Answer is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_by_country#Abolition_chronology).  Please document prior research.

Answer (score 14):

This answer is thoroughly non original, as it is drawn extensively from Wikipedia's article on the topic. According to this source, Tuscany officially abolished the death penalty in 1786. Of course, this presumably does not count, because Tuscany was later absorbed into Italy, which reinstated it in Tuscany in 1927 under the Fascist regime. So, again according to this article, the nation-state which has officially abolished death penalty for the longest period of time is Venezuela, which abolished it in 1854, so well after Michigan. However, one possible contender would be San Marino, which abolished death penalty "only" in 1865 but which carried out its last execution in 1468.

All in all, if this article is to be trusted, then Michigan seems indeed to be the legal entity which holds the record of *de jure* abolition, with San Marino by far the record holder for *de facto* abolition.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment#Abolitionism

Comment: Last paragraph has it. While we are throwing in extraneous factoids though, it was outlawed in ancient Japan for most of the [Heian period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heian_Period) (the entire time the [Minamotos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minamoto_clan) were ruling, to be specific. 338 years.) I believe that's the current record holder for longest official abolition.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I'm not sure if modern Japan also has no death penalty, but I get the impression that WWII Japan, at least, had the death penalty, given its "death marches," etc. So I would not credit Japan with "continuous" abolition of the death penalty, even it was abolished for 338 years in an earlier epoch.

Comment: @TomAu Japan has the death penalty and in fact regularly executes convicts but I believe that T.E.D's point is that 338 years of abolition is the longest official abolition on record, even if it was ultimately reinstated.

Comment: The state of Michigan was established in 1837.  Did it actually execute anyone before 1846, or has it never executed anyone?

Comment: @CMonsour As a state (so from 1837), Michigan never executed anyone.

Answer (score -3):

For further information see also here:

[What was the biggest empire that never had capital punishment?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55137/what-was-the-biggest-empire-that-never-had-capital-punishment/55138#55138)[1](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55137/what-was-the-biggest-empire-that-never-had-capital-punishment/55138#55138)

And here: https://historum.com/threads/was-emperor-xuanzong-of-tang-the-first-monarch-to-abolish-the-death-penalty.180620/[2](https://historum.com/threads/was-emperor-xuanzong-of-tang-the-first-monarch-to-abolish-the-death-penalty.180620/)

And here:

https://historum.com/threads/which-was-the-first-country-to-abolish-the-death-penalty.124922/[3](https://historum.com/threads/which-was-the-first-country-to-abolish-the-death-penalty.124922/)

Comment: Link-only answers [are discouraged](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)